# parentNode or previousElementSibling not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have some javascript, and either parentNode or previviousElementSibling seems to be breaking in IE8.  The code works fine in firefox and IE9.  This is the line that's not getting implemented:

```
$(submitter.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling).children('#mark_as_broken').show();
```

code is something like

```
<form><div><input id=mark_as_broken></input></div></form>
<form><div><input id=mark_as_fixed></input></div></form>
```

where the mark_as_fixed input is the submitter.  This works on other browsers.

any ideas which bit of it won't work, and why?

Comment: What does the markup look like? What does "submitter" reference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`previousElementSibling` is not supported until IE9.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t84

Here's a function that should work. <s>Haven't tested it yet.</s> Seems to work.

```
var previousElementSibling = function( el ) {
    if( el.previousElementSibling ) {
        return el.previousElementSibling;
    } else {
        while( el = el.previousSibling ) {
            if( el.nodeType === 1 ) return el;
        }
    }
}

$( previousElementSibling(submitter.parentNode.parentNode) )
```

---

**EDIT:**

You didn't mention jQuery, but you appear to be using its API. If so, you can just do this:

```
$(submitter).closest('form').prev().find('#mark_as_broken').show();
```

Based on your markup, it appears as though you should be using `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

Comment: can you explain this function - it seems to be recursive, though I am quite scrappy at javascript

Comment: @tiswas: If the property is supported, it just uses that. If not, then as long as there's a `previousSibling`, it overwrites `el` with that, then tests to see if it is a type 1 element, and if so it returns it. If it gets to a point where there's no `previousSibling` at all, the `while` loop breaks, and `undefined` is returned by default.