# how can i generate a textbox with a button to close both of it dynamically using js DOM?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function show() {
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';
        textbox.id = "textBox";
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = "X";
        btn.id = "button";
        btn.onclick = close;
        document.getElementById("display").appendChild(textbox);
        document.getElementById("display").appendChild(btn);
    }

    function close() {
        document.getElementById("textBox").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="show()">add contact</a>
    <div id="display">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code I was manged to generate the textbox with a button.
when we click on the button in the first generating textbox button pair it is working.
but it is not working or multiple pairs.
I need to close each pair by clicking the button in the each pair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding input elements dynamically to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute [**`id`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, use [**`class`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead to refer multiple elements with same attribute. You can use [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object to refer the currently clicked button so that you can remove the correct element.

**Try the following way:**

```js
function show(){
  var textbox = document.createElement('input');
  textbox.type = 'text';
  textbox.id = "textBox";
  var btn =document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML ="X";
  btn.class="button";
  btn.onclick = close;
  document.getElementById("display").appendChild(textbox);
  document.getElementById("display").appendChild(btn);
}
function close(){
  this.previousElementSibling.remove();
  this.remove();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick = "show()">add contact</a>
<div id = "display"></div>
```

**Please Note:** [**`previousElementSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) is not supported until IE9.

In that  case please refer: [parentNode or previousElementSibling not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197825/parentnode-or-previouselementsibling-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: The previousElementSibling property is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions.

Comment: @harry, if the answer solve your question then you can upvote and accept  the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*...thanks:)