# Get the width of a child element in javascript? Rails template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find the width of a child element. My template is in rails:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id = "inner"></div>
        <%= image_tag(photo.file_name) %>
 </div>
```

I want to get the width of the image after "inner" using javascript. Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep it straight Javascript without additional libs

```
img =document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('img');
 for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
   console.log(img[i].clientWidth)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the only thing in the "wrapper" div other than the "inner" div, something like this will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/842346/1960453

Either use jQuery, or altCognito's function to get the width of the sibling of the "inner" div