# translating css3 selector to javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I need to adapt some css code to javascript.

I have next code, and I need to adapt it to javascript objects, through **.style** of javascript object.

With attributes, I'm doing well, but with selectors I have to develop with javascript actions (for calling it in anyway) :)

```
.cr-container input:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span{
    -webkit-animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
    animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: What don't you understand? What are you having trouble with? Have you looked at `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: I dont understand why people up to the cloud and are such as offensive...My question is clear: traduce/translate that code to javascript...I obtained, by style.setProperty("-webkit-animation", "left 150px"); and style.setProperty("-moz-animation", "left 150px"); for mozilla firefox...thanks

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking how to set properties, find matching elements, or update new elements.  Also, StackOverflow questions are expected to show a modicum of effort; both of those questions are basic, easily-Googleable tasks.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".cr-container input:checked");
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

For jQuery:

If think what you want is:

```
$(".cr-container input:checked")
```

As you can see it's not that different.

or

```
 $(".cr-container > input:checked")
```

Doc:

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: What main the ~ after input:checked?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, i gave you a jquery answer, did you want a pure javascript one?

Comment: Ye... Just noticed. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. The **~** operator is to select all sibling element in the DOM
2. **:checked** is the pseudo-class to select radio-buttons et check-boxes which are checked
3. The **.** is to select the HTML element with the class

This should work :

```
$('.cr-container input:checked').siblings('.cr-bgimg div span')
```

Comment: I thought so too but he's not looking for jQuery. Just javascript

Comment: but I need not for jquery, please dear

Comment: Have a look to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes