# how to get an id beneath an other id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get an id that is under an other id like this:

```
<p id="moe1" onclick="moe()">Mamamia</p>
<p id="socket1">Pizzaria</p>
```

So if i know that my id is "moe1", how can i find what is the id under "moe1"?

Comment: What do you mean by _under_? A sibling element? A child (nested) element?

Comment: From the example i figure he means the next sibling.

Comment: Use `next()` in jquery. [http://api.jquery.com/next/](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: Why do you need to get the ID if you can get the element itself?

Comment: The only _example_ is the `HTML` markup. I can't see any `Javascript` in the question, which means: Can you guys code it for me (for free)?

Comment: Naturally. this is why he's getting downvotes.

Comment: `document.getElementById('moe1').nextElementSibling.id`

Comment: @MelanciaUK It's knowledge for the community. I don't care about someone being lazy (if he really is).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is there a way to select sibling nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes)

Answer (score -1):

you could use [CSS adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

```
document.querySelector("#moe1 + p").id
```

or for all elements not only p tags

```
 document.querySelector("#moe1 + *").id
```

Answer (score -1):

This line of code worked for me:

```
document.getElementById('moe1').nextSibling;
```