# Selecting a child node of a sibling with Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, nodes, children, siblings

I'm trying to find a way to select a child node of a sibling node with pure Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Select from where? Do you mean in a selector string? `".foo + .bar > .baz"` Or do you mean from an element you have a reference to? `my_foo.nextElementSibling.children[0]` Please be more specific. Is it something other than the very next sibling? There are too many ways to interpret this.

Comment: This question shows how to get all the siblings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes/22799075#22799075. Getting the children should be an easy addition.

Comment: yeah from an element I have a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`querySelector`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp). But you to take care of `browser version`.

```js
alert(document.querySelector('#sibling1 ~ #sibling2').children[0].innerHTML); // give desired child index
```

```html
<div id="sibling1">sibling1</div>
<div id="sibling2">
    <div id="sibling2-child">sibling2-child-1</div>
    <div id="sibling3-child">sibling2-child-2</div>
</div>
```