# Refer to a nearby element DOM Js

Tags: javascript

How will I address the elements that are nearby?

I have this html

```
<button class="prev" onclick="prevtrack">Prev</button>
<button class="next" onclick="nexttrack">Next</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Need this item (Prev)</li>
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li>Need this item (Next)</li>
    </ul>
```

But there may be such an option

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>Need this item</li>
    <li class="active"></li>
</ul>
```

nth: it does not suit me (because I need a number of Nearby elements)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBaDS.png)

Comment: Are they always siblings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to select sibling nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes)

Comment: Give the id or `data-` attribute to each `li`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I have a button that should click on the item that is after the active element

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко  that is not a good way to identify it

Comment: @Aluan Haddad What is your offer?

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко  Use `id` or perhaps `class`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad element button one!

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко  sorry I don't understand

Comment: @Aluan Haddad i have One button! and this button haved click function

Comment: @Aluan Haddad i have button player (>>|) and this button clicked element li

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. Why don't you add the code for the event handler

Comment: I want to click on the button which in turn will click on the neighboring element of the active <li>

Comment: @Aluan Haddad i shared image, i clicked on button NEXT and this click go to <li>

Comment: I refuse to look at an image. Post the code as text

Comment: @Aluan Haddad 
<ul>
    <li>Need this item</li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li>Need this item</li>
</ul>

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко you keep repeating yourself but you're not making yourself clearer

Comment: @Aluan Haddad  , i edit Html in question

Comment: I'm voting to close this as you haven't provided an MVCE

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I found a solution, See my answer!

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко it's of even lower quality than the question

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my question

```
$("li.active").prev().children('a').click();
```