# Adding class to table row has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to do two things in pure Javascript when the user clicks a table:

1. return the number of the row (it works)
2. change the background of the row

Here my current code:

```js
document.querySelector('#tableEvents').onclick = function(e) {
  let index = e.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
  let row = e.target.parentElement;
  row.classList.add('table-warning');
  console.log(index, row.classList.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="tableEvents">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Col 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Col 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-group-divider">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>3c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>4d</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, it returns the correct index but no changes are made to the row.
Reading the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#variants) I understand it should be enough to add the `table-warning` class (for example) to the `<tr>` tag.

It actually adds the class (the console shows the `classList` value) but no color is shown.

The second issue is how to remove the class from the other rows. In jQuery I would do:

```
$(this).addClass('table-warning').siblings().removeClass('table-warning');
```

but I don't understand how to convert the `siblings()` call in JavaScript.
Do I need to traverse the whole table, removing the class from each row manually?

Comment: @Lapskaus why do you say I didn't post the css? It's the default bootstrap css, as per the link stylesheet in the snippet. I don't have any other custom css

Comment: I didnt realize you were using the bootstrap theming. My bad. Ignore the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now just loop all the sibling rows except that one, and remove the class, no jQuery needed (here's a few based upon approaches how to do it with vanilla JS: [Is there a way to select sibling nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes))

Also, you need to add `table` class for the `table-warning` helper class to work:

```js
document.querySelector('#tableEvents').onclick = function(e) {
  let index = e.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
  // skip header
  if(index===0 || !index) return;
  
  let row = e.target.parentElement;
  row.classList.add('table-warning');
  console.log(index, row.classList.toString());
      
    let siblingRow = row.parentNode.firstChild;

    
    while (siblingRow) {

        if (siblingRow.nodeType === 1 && siblingRow !== row) {

            siblingRow.classList.remove('table-warning');
      
        }
        siblingRow = siblingRow.nextSibling;
    }
  
 
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important; bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table" id="tableEvents">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Col 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Col 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-group-divider">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>3c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>4d</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works only if I add the `.table-warning` definition in the CSS. But Bootstrap already has this (follow the link in the original question). Why does not work with the default class?

Comment: try now, with `bg-warning` instead

Comment: you're right, but the documentation explicitly says that `table-<variant>` works for tables, rows and cells! `<tr class="table-primary">...</tr>` is in the link above! `bg-warning` is not present in the whole page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/

Comment: aah, no, it's because you're missing `.table` class.. : `table class="table" ...`. Now it's working, try it

Comment: yeah, chasing red herrings is always fun